# How to manage Http sessions? (without external libraries)

Tags: java, session

I'm working on a <strike>servlet</strike> Http and WebSocket server and I'm wondering what's the best way to implement session ids for the clients.

I'm thinking of setting the id as a cookie on the client side and save it in memory on the server side since that's what I commonly see doing.

But let's say **client A** makes its first request to the server and A receives its session id from the server, let's call that **A_SESSION** for the purpose of clarity.
At this point the server knows that A_SESSION identifies client A.

Let's say that client A has bad intentions and as soon as it receives the session id it sets a bunch of variables and fills them with data through some API the server provides, then it **clears the session** id and makes another request for a **new session**, it won't be long before the server will have a large number of useless variables set in memory which are not null and can't be garbage collected.

1. **How would you save that data?** 
    The first thing that comes to mind is to save those variables in a `Map<String,Object>` where each key of the map is the session id and the Object is the data (maybe another `Map<>` or `JsonObject`?).
2. **When would you delete the data?** 
    Do you simply set a TTL variable?
3. Most importantly, and you could argue this should've been my first question: **Is there a way to generate the same session id for the same client machine and still be secure?**

I'm not posting any code because it's pretty long and I doubt it would be relevant to the question, this is more of a policy question rather than a coding question.

But I still think I should provide some more context and let you know what kind of client information I have access to.

When I say I'm not using any external libraries I mean I'm not using any libraries other than the core Java ones.

I manage the http connections by directly using a ServerSocket and Socket objects, like this

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket();
ss.bind(new InetSocketAddress(bindAddress, port));
init();
while(true){
    new HttpEventListener(ss.accept()).start();
}
```

and `HttpEventListener` is where I manage the clients basically.
I've got the clients' ip addresses, the request header, and ofc I can identify each connection as a `Socket`.

Comment: 1. You seem to ignore the fact that the servlet API provides native support for sessions. Why would you reinvent the wheel? 2. If you're concerned about memory used by the session data, then design your app as a stateless app: don't store anything, other than the user ID, in the session. Or don't use sessions at all and use, for example, a JWT token. Or read the container documentation to learn how to store sessions on disk rather than memory.

Comment: I'm not using HttpServlet to create my http connection, I'm using plain sockets.

Comment: Then please don't start your post with "I'm working on a servlet". Anyway, if you want to learn how to handle sessions by yourself, then learn how servlets do that, and do the same thing.

Comment: I thought a sevlet is a program that serves web content/http requests?That's the point of the post... I was looking for help here

Comment: No. A servlet is a servlet, as defined by the servlet specifications. Not just a random piece of code serving HTTP requests.

Comment: I see! Can you point me in the right direction regarding how servlets manage sessions? Some book or online reference?

Comment: https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/DOWNLOADS.html